# Using wrong character set

Tags: encoding, internationalization

I have an old text file from an old Mac, and I'm pretty sure I'm using the wrong character set.  Opening quotes show up as Ò, closing quote as Ó, and apostrophes show up as Õ.  I'm not sure where to look to find which encoding the original file used.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out

Comment: Please don't leave us in the dark and answer your own question below in *Your Answer*

Answer (score 1):

It's MacRoman being read as if it were iso-8859-1 or similar.  This chart shows the codes  http://www.alanwood.net/demos/macroman.html